# .htaccess: Redirect pages if not accessed within subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

Scenario:

```
Main domain domain.com points to */home/domain/www*
Addon domain addon.com points to */home/domain/www/addon/www*
```

Question: How do I do the following:

```
http://addon.domain.com instead of http://domain.com/addon
http://addon.domain.com/page.html instead of http://domain.com/addon/page.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding these rules to the htaccess file in the `/home/domain/www` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^addon/?(.*)$ http://addon.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```